# Print String After Sub-Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, concatenation

I've been trying to concatenate a string within a self-defined subprogram in python. It looks like this:

```
def StockXValueStr(stockBurgerValue, stockBurgerValueStr):
    stockBurgerValueStr += "s"
    print(stockBurgerValueStr)
```

The original value of stockBurgerValue is "10", and this prints out `stockBurgerValueStr` fine. The issue occurs when I try to print `stockBurgerValueStr` again outside of the subprogram. It simply prints the original value of `stockBurgerValueStr ("10")`. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](//stackoverflow.com/q/575196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stockBurgerValueStr becomes a local variable inside the subprogram

```
StockXValueStr()
```

And does not actually get changed. In other words, the subprogram only gets a copy of the variables and cant change the values from outside the subprogram. if you want to keep the subprogram you can try

```
def StockXValueStr(stockBurgerValue, stockBurgerValueStr):
    stockBurgerValueStr += "s"
   return stockBurgerValueStr

stockBurgerValueStr = StockXValueStr(stockBurgerValue, stockBurgerValueStr)
```